# Non-box shadow in CSS

Tags: css

I have looked into creating `box-shadow`s in CSS but how can we make non-box-shadows? I have triangle made with one of the CSS Tricks and I want some shadow around it's sides but when I add `box-shadow` it adds a box around it and then adds a shadow. How can I achieve this?

This is what happens: [Demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/sqy7V/2/)

Comment: This isn't possible. The way the triangles work to begin with is a hack. Your best bet is using SVG.

Comment: This might be helpful: http://demosthenes.info/blog/598/boxshadow-property-vs-dropshadow-filter-a-complete-comparison

Comment: Best odd is to use an image incl. drop-shadow, canvas to produce the triangle with shadow or svg. The first option is cross-browser and even works in older browsers. The image would be tiny so you could include it directly in your CSS in data-uri form..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course it is possible. With `filter: drop-shadow` you can even add shadows to transparent png shapes.

Params are pretty much the same as for `box-shadow`:

```
-webkit-filter: drop-shadow(1px 1px 5px #000);
filter: drop-shadow(1px 1px 5px #000);
```

**NOTE** drop-shadow works only with webkit engines (Opera, Chrome and Safari) - thanks to **Eliran Malka** for pointing that out.

Comment: nice, but it's worth noting this is still a working draft, and [not widely supported](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-filters).

Comment: not true, [`box-shadow` is supported in all major browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-boxshadow), while [`filter` is supported only on webkit engines](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-filters).

Comment: @EliranMalka this is support chart for box-shadow. Where's for drop-shadow?

Comment: i couldn't find one for `drop-shadow`, because there is not such a property, `drop-shadow` only exists as a value for the `filter` property. and you did claim that *"it is supported as much as box-shadow"*.

Comment: well, the new `filter` implementation you offer to use (and not the IE filter), does. again, take a look at the [compatibility chart](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-filters). i certainly know what i am talking about. and i *did* upvote your answer :)

Comment: are you serious? [take a look at the *current* row](http://i.imgur.com/NxzKdqn.png).

Comment: Just checked again, you were right. Take my apology. For the project I used, there was darker image, bright parent gradient background and as I used white for the shadow, it gave me an illusion. Changed shadow to red and it doesn't work.

Comment: sure, no harm. as a sidenote, however, it is still a good practice to use all vendor prefixes (e.g. `-o-`, `-moz-`), as you did in the first version of your answer, for *future* compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, it isn't possible to give a CSS shape a shadow. Two alternatives are to -

- duplicate the CSS shape using perhaps :before or :after, then z-index it underneath and position it to the lower-right
- use images for the shape and add the shadow effect to the image (if you have Photoshop, this is done through the layer drop shadow filter)